# OpenTSDB indexing on keys

Tags: opentsdb

As I've worked in my personal lab instance of OpenTSDB, I've started to wonder if it is possible to get it to index on tags as well as metric names.  My understanding (correction is welcome...) is that OpenTSDB indexes only on metric names.  So, suppose I have something like the following, borrowed from the docs:

**tsd.hbase.rpcs{type=*,host=tsd1}**

My understanding is that **tsd.hbase.rpcs** is indexed for searching, but that the keys (type=, host=, etc) are not.  Is that correct?  If so, is there a way to have them be indexed, or some reasonable approximation of it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, according to [the documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/backends/hbase.html), OpenTSDB creates keys in the 'tsdb' HBase table of the form

```
[salt]<metric_uid><timestamp><tagk1><tagv1>[...<tagkN><tagvN>]
```

When you do a query with specific tagk and tagv OpenTSDB can construct the key and look it up. If you have a range of tagk and tagv it will look up all the rows and either aggregate them or return multiple time series, depending on your query.

If you are interested in asking questions about tagks, you should use the [OpenTSDB search/lookup api](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/search/lookup.html), however this still requires a metric name.

If you want to formulate your question around tagks only, you could consider forwarding your data to Bosun for indexing and using [its API](https://bosun.org/api)

> /api/metric/{tagk}/{tagv}
>
> Returns the metrics that are available for the specified tagk/tagv pair. For example, you can see what metrics are available for host=server01

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I suspected, but I appreciate the confirmation.